# Sorting array based on value (number) - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to sort an array by descending on a number, all values in the array have 0 by default but some items in the array will increase to 1,2,3,4. I would like to see a list with 4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 and this in alphabetical order. Alphabetizing the 0 series was successful. Only I get the sorting done when the value 1 is assigned but not anymore.

the field `'nearest'` is the value in the object where 0,1,2,3,4 will be placed

This is my sort:

```
            this.state.locations.sort(function(a, b) {
                if(a.nearest) return -1;
                if(b.nearest) return 1;
                if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
                if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
                return 0;
               }).map((marker, i) => (
```

Does anyone have a clear view / explanation on this?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (a.nearest != b.nearest) return b.nearest - a.nearest`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Supplementing the comment of Ja͢ck, you never actually compare `a.nearest` and `b.nearest`. You only check if they contain a truthy or falsy value. If `a.nearest` is anything other then `0`, `-1` will be returned. If `b.nearest` is anything other than `0`, `1` will be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer I'll assume that you want to sort by nearest first, if nearest is the same then sort by name.

The issue lies in the first two lines of you sort function:

```
if(a.nearest) return -1;
if(b.nearest) return 1;
```

You check only for truthy or falsy values for `a.nearest` and `b.nearest`. This means that if either `a.nearest` or `b.nearest` is present (not `0`) you never compare the names.

Take for example the following scenario where `a.nearest = 1` and `b.nearest = 2`. Since `a.nearest` is not falsy, `-1` is returned, moving `a` before `b` while `b` has the greater `nearest` value.

Instead you want to compare them against each other, and only move on to name comparison if they are the same (taken from [Ja͢ck's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726387/sorting-array-based-on-value-number-react-native#comment107441767_60726387)):

```
this.state.locations.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.nearest != b.nearest) return b.nearest - a.nearest;
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
  if (a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

This checks if `a.nearest` and `b.nearest` are not the same. Then returns a negative number if `a.nearest` is greater than `b.nearest`, moving `a` further to the front of the collection. It returns a positive number if `a.nearest` is smaller than `b.nearest`, moving `a` further to the back of the collection. If both `nearest` values are the same the *if* is skipped and the next statement is executed.

I'd also like to add that React specifically asks [not to modify the state yourself](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly), but use the `setState` handle.

> #### Do Not Modify State Directly
>
> For example, this will not re-render a component:
>
> ```
> // Wrong
> this.state.comment = 'Hello';
> ```
>
> Instead, use `setState()`:
>
> ```
> // Correct
> this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
> ```
>
> The only place where you can assign `this.state` is the constructor.

[`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts the array in place, meaning that the receiver will be mutaded.

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array [*in place*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

You should thus first make a copy before sorting. This can be done with for example [`locations.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`[...locations]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [`Array.from(locations)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and probably a few others.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of local compare string too. here is the best combination.

```js
let locations = [
      { nearest: 0, name: "1" },
      { nearest: 0, name: "5" },
      { nearest: 4, name: "2" },
      { nearest: 4, name: "3" },
      { nearest: 1, name: "2" },
      { nearest: 1, name: "1" }
    ];

    locations = locations.sort(function(a, b) {
      const nearestA = a.nearest || 0;
      const nearestB = b.nearest || 0;
      const nameA = a.name || "";
      const nameB = b.name || "";
      if ((nearestA || nearestB) && (nearestA != nearestB)) return nearestB - nearestA;
      return nameA.toLowerCase().localeCompare(nameB.toLowerCase());
    });
    console.log(locations);
```

Comment: `if (nearestA || nearestB)` is incorrect and only checks for presence of the value. If either `nearestA` or `nearestB` is present they are always compared using `nearestB - nearestA` when they are the same it is not followed up by a name comparison. This should be `if (nearestA != nearestB)`.

Comment: lol, this is number compare. I have already defined default value 0. It will work fine. U can add data and run. It will work. Else give me data to test.

Comment: Your current test data fails. `{nearest: 1, name: "2"}` is located before `{nearest: 1, name: "1"}` in the output. This should be the other way around, since names should be sorted alphabetically (when `nearest` is the same).